# Python: How to sum two signed int16 arrays into one without overflow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, audio, wav

I have several int16 streams in strings and I want them sum together (without overflow) and return it as an int16 string. Background is mixing several wave files into one stream.

```
decodeddata1 = numpy.fromstring(data, numpy.int16)
decodeddata2 = numpy.fromstring(data2, numpy.int16)
newdata = decodeddata1 + decodeddata2
return newdata.tostring()
```

Is there a way doing this with numpy or is there another library?

Processing each single value in python is too slow and results in stutter.

The most important thing is performance, since this code is used in a callback method feeding the audio.

@edit:

```
test input data:
a = np.int16([20000,20000,-20000,-20000])
b = np.int16([10000,20000,-10000,-20000])
print a + b -->   [ 30000 -25536 -30000  25536]
```

but I want to keep the maximum levels:
[ 30000 40000 -30000  -40000]

Comment: Can you provide some example input and expected output data?

Comment: So you want sum with clipping?

Comment: but this doesn't make much sense, the max for an int16 is 32767, you won't have 40000 as int16

Answer (score 1):

The obvious consequence of mixing two signals together with a dynamic range of `-32768<x<32767` is a resulting signal of with range of `-65537<x<65536` - which requires `17` bits to represent it.

To avoid clipping, you will need to gain-scale the inputs - the obvious way is to divide the sum (or both of the inputs) by `2`.

`numpy` looks as thought it should be quite fast for this - at least faster than python's builtin variable-size integer type.    If the additional arithmetic is a performance concern, you should consider your choice of language.